# Terraform aws security group change

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

When I run Terraform apply and a plan after, there is always another modification to the security group that is outstanding. I don't quite understand how to read this. Can someone shed some light?

```
terraform plan
~ module.emr.aws_security_group.ds-emr-master
ingress.#:                                       "3" => "4"

ingress.2364643915.cidr_blocks.#:                "0" => "2"
ingress.2364643915.cidr_blocks.0:                "" => "34.x.x.x/32"
ingress.2364643915.cidr_blocks.1:                "" => "172.x.x.x/32"
ingress.2364643915.from_port:                    "" => "0"
ingress.2364643915.protocol:                     "" => "-1"
ingress.2364643915.self:                         "" => "false"
ingress.2364643915.to_port:                      "" => "0"

ingress.3989612637.cidr_blocks.#:                "2" => "0"
ingress.3989612637.cidr_blocks.0:                "34.x.x.x/32" => ""
ingress.3989612637.cidr_blocks.1:                "172.x.x.x/32" => ""
ingress.3989612637.protocol:                     "-1" => ""
ingress.3989612637.security_groups.#:            "1" => "0"
ingress.3989612637.security_groups.3719875660:   "sg-xxxxx" => ""

ingress.4127332019.from_port:                    "" => "0"
ingress.4127332019.protocol:                     "" => "-1"
ingress.4127332019.security_groups.#:            "0" => "1"
ingress.4127332019.security_groups.3719875660:   "" => "sg-xxxxx"
ingress.4127332019.self:                         "" => "false"
ingress.4127332019.to_port:                      "" => "0"
```

Comment: Can you include your Terraform template, or at least the relevant parts?

Comment: Looks like an open issue https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/9514

Comment: I recommend making security groups that don't contain any rules in the `aws_security_group `. Make the rules as seperate resources. It's buggy to do them in the `aws_security_group ` itself.